# Are $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION and $_COOKIES in PHP the only way to pass variables from page to page?

Tags: php, variables, session

The question speaks for itself, but is there any other method?

Could you kindly share them even if those are the best practices?

Comment: Think again: What is your current situation/what specificly do you need. Is there a PHP implementation, such as `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc. for this? If not, research. If you don't find any, ask again

Comment: It's just curiosity, I could not find other methods, but I don't know half of them... For me $_SESSION is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the most obvious ways to input information into a page. It is possible to parse the input from the url in another way than `$_GET`, but why would you.

Also, you can use other methods. For instance, you could save information in a file or database and read it in the next page, although you might still need some information in a cookie or the url to identify which information to read (session id).

So, while strictly the answer to your question is 'no', I want to say 'yes', these are the methods you will commonly use.

If it's strictly about those global variables, then you've got the `$_REQUEST` variable, which basically collects all values from `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` together. And `$_FILES` gives information about uploaded files, which are automatically stored in a temporary location, although in essence, those files are also posted to the page. So, these globals help you making things easy regarding the most common methods to communicate with a script.

All these are for input, by the way. You cannot send information back, or to the next page, by modifying these [*`$_SUPERGLOBALS`*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: Thank you, it covered the answer quite well, although I was looking for something else but now I know what to look/ask for. Another form of passing the information would be the answer from @cartalot [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797817/3347137)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on *what* you're trying to do.

- Are you passing form or request data? Then GET and POST are your best
  methods.
- Temporary data about the user? SESSION is your best method.
- Permanent data or data that should persist longer than a single use
  session? Then it should be stored in a database, or in rare cases a
  flat file.

Comment: What I was trying to do was passing a variable from the class file thru <form action file> to main page, and I found $_SESSION that suits me but I'd like to know if there is another method.
Because I have to return false from the class to the <form action file> and I handle the error there to show to the user after that.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a structuring problem. It's hard to tell without knowing exactly how your program is structured, but you shouldn't need to add that variable to session just to be used in a function, you should be passing that variable as an argument to whatever function in your class is being used in your form action script.

Comment: What I'm basically doing is if the class returns false at certain point the `$_SESSIO['name_error'] = "invalid name";` or at some other point `$_SESSIO['name_error'] = "not found";` or if everything is fine `$_SESSIO['name_error'] = "OK";` and them showing it to the user on the main page.
What I wasn't able to do is to have a `$name_error = "foo"` on the class file and showing it in the main page without using `$_SESSION`.

And that's why I asked if there is any other method to search and try with it but everywhere I look it seems `$_SESSION` is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

so i guess technically this is covered by post - but an alternative to sessions - which are written to the cookie and therefore are completely cookie dependent - is to use a "token" which is passed in a hidden form field.

typically the token is a long random string - that you retrieve and then use as the key or id for your session table. passed inside a hidden form field, and on SSL https pages - it completely eliminates having to set and retrieve user cookie sessions which can be a big advantage for applications where you need the widest possible adoption (some people have cookies turned off, blocked, etc).

Comment: I thought that `$_SESSION` was stored on the server and could not be "blocked" by browser. I read something about the hidden form field but it was applying when the user inputs some data and them it goes to a summary page or returning from summary page to the form page.

Comment: the php session is stored on the server but the session identifier - PHPSESSID - is stored on the browser cookie. the server sends and gets the session id in the document header. therefore if browser cookies are disabled or there is any other issue with users cookies - the session id will not be recognized and sessions will not function. VERSUS sending a 'token' - same idea as a session id - in a secure form - thereby eliminating cookies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will research more about that and test it before anything.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, more Globals:

> $_REQEUST - Includes $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE
>
> $_FILES - uploaded file datas (like name, type, e.g)

Comment: I will look further for them. The only one I've tried was `$_FILES` beside the ones I've placed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you could store a value in the database and then retrieve it with a query.
Other than that I thin you covered all of them

Comment: This is true, although you'd need one of the aforementioned approaches in order to link the two requests together!

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'd like to have something as instant and not long term.

Answer (score -2):

> Are $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION and $_COOKIES in PHP the only way to pass variables from page to page?

No.

There are no "best practices". Every practice best fits for the particular task. Got any?

Also, all the above are just PHP superglobal variables, not whatever "ways", and cannnot "pass" anything just by itself

Also note that you cannot pass variables anywhere. A variable may belong to the executed script only. While you can pass only some values of string type.

Comment: Give some alternative examples :-)